# csh: How to save the shell environment (env, current dir, shell history) in a file and set it on another shell?

Tags: shell, csh

I start interactive terminal using farm (LSF). These terminals get opened on some random host and get closed automatically after 15 days. I want to save the current shell environment (env, current directory, aliases, history of shell, ...) in a file. I would like to save the setting on periodically or on the 14th day. So, when the current shell terminates, I will relaunch a new terminal and set the same environment from the saved file. This will help in getting the almost the same shell again.